# Deleting several frames from an animated GIF file at once in GIMP

Tags: windows-7, gimp, animated-gif

When opening an animated GIF file in GIMP, it lists all frames:

[image]

How to delete several frames from an animated GIF file at once in GIMP?

To deleted one frame, one can right click, then "delete layer":

[image]

but I couldn't find a way to delete several frames at once. (holding  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. There is no way to select multiple layers yet.

Longer answer: A workaround would be to write a script that adds itself to the Layers menu and offers to delete a set number of layers.

Comment: "Write a script"  This ain't no Paint.NET ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the said script in the accepted answer.

Depending on how much frames you want to get rid of (you can change the 3 in `index%3` below) you can copy paste this in **Filters -> Python-Fu -> Console**

```
image = gimp.image_list()[0]
for (index,layer) in enumerate(image.layers):
  if not index%3:
    image.remove_layer(layer)
```

And press enter twice. This will remove one frame for every three frames in your file.

Also note that you have **Filters -> Animation -> Optimize (For GIF)** to reduce size.